# How to colorize Segoe MDL2 Icons in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am looking for a way to add colour to Segoe MDL2 icons. The glyphs in my application are currently TextBlock resources, defined like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="PenSymbol" x:Shared="False" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE76D;" FontSize="16" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Grayscale"/>
```

The effect I'm after is the one in the left 3 icons:
[image: SketchPad Toolbar]

This is a screenshot of the toolbar in Window 10 Sketchpad (after applying the Creators update).

Edit: I know how to change the text colour, I am trying to figure out how to get the "partial fill"-effect (blue, black and yellow in the screenshot).

Edit2: It is necessary to display 2 different glyphs to achieve this effect. The glyphs necessary for the background were added to the Segoe MDL2 font in the last update. Thanks to mm8 for pointing me in the right direction.

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="SymbolText" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="Grayscale"/>
</Style>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid Margin="4">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE88F;" Style="{StaticResource SymbolText}" Foreground="OrangeRed"/>
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE76D;" Style="{StaticResource SymbolText}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="4">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xF0C6;" Style="{StaticResource SymbolText}" Foreground="LightGreen"/>
        <TextBlock Text="&#xED63;" Style="{StaticResource SymbolText}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="4">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE891;" Style="{StaticResource SymbolText}" Foreground="LightBlue"/>
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE193;" Style="{StaticResource SymbolText}"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `Foreground` property to a `Brush`:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="PenSymbol" x:Shared="False" Foreground="Red" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE76D;" FontSize="16"/>
```

Othwerwise layering and colorization effects can be achieved by drawing glyphs directly on top of each other as stated in the documentation on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've read that page before; it says you can do that, but not how. It's also for UWP, so I'm not even entirely sure you can do the same thing in WPF. I've also updated the original question to make it clearer I'm not looking to change the foreground.

Comment: What would be the difference betwee UWP and WPF in this regard?

Comment: I am afraid there is no other "magic" way of filling only a part of character of a TextBlock. You should create your own custom symbols or place the glyphs on top of each other.

Comment: Ok I just realized 2 things: the heart thing is composed of 2 different glyphs, one filled and one outline. I thought the effect could be done with the same glyph and different property settings. The 2nd thing I realized is that the last Windows update changed the Segoe MDL2 font itself - I'll go through it again to see if there are new glyphs I can use for applying the fill colour (so far I found one for the pencil but not for the pen and highlighter).

Answer (score 5):

You can put one gliph over another and colorize it this way. Example:

```
<Grid>
    <FontIcon Foreground="#f8d876" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE8D5;" />
    <FontIcon  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE8B7;" />
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made this and it works:

I've added a grid under a button, added two labels with MDL 2 icons and with some alignment it's an help button with a circular background!

```
<Button>
  <Grid>
    <Label Content='&#xEA3B;' Foreground="#FFBFBEBF" />
    <Label Content='&#xE897;' Foreground="#FF0066FF" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>
</Button>
```